# generate all k-Permutations from n+1 without recalculate the k-permutations from n python 3

Tags: python, algorithm

My task is to calculate the k-permutations from the updated List by new element
without recalculating the k-permutations already gotten from the previous state of the list. Example:

```
liste = [1, 2, 3]
```

3-permutations are:

```
[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]
```

The updated list:

```
liste = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I would like to obtain directly `3-permutations[1, 2, 3, 4]-3-permutations[1, 2, 3]`
without recalculating `3-permutations[1, 2, 3]`

Calculate directly the new permutations:

```
[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1],
[2, 4, 3], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], 
[4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2]
```

Thanks

Comment: the List is updated progressively by adding one new element.

Comment: as shown before:

Comment: from [1,2,3] to [1,2,3,4] and then [1,2,3,4,5]........

Comment: and at each step we calculate the k-permutations for the new element with the existing ones

Comment: yes, we can say that it's a rule, always increase the list by only one element.

Comment: sorry i didn't remark that, no it could be another value, so yes it could be 999.

Comment: ?? I did not ask you any question, you must be mistaken!

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe, if you think it is important, you could flag this for a moderator to look into. Comments can be deleted, and it seems that it was. (I have not seen the comment BTW).

Comment: can anyone tell me if this problem can be solved by the"Gray code", if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Computing first the cartesian product {0,1,2,3}x{0,1,2}x{0,1} and taking the nth element of list (1,2,3,4).</s>

```
r=[]
for prd in itertools.product([[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,1]]):
    l=[1,2,3,4]
    r0=[]
    for i in prd:
        r0 += l[i]
        del l[i]
    r += r0
```

EDIT: original answer gives the 3-permutations of [1,2,3,4]

following command answers specifically to question, see how it can be generalized

```
[list(j) for i in itertools.combinations([1,2,3],2) for j in itertools.permutations(list(i)+[4])]
```

next case, maybe one of ?

```
[list(j) for i in itertools.combinations([1,2,3],2) for j in itertools.permutations(list(i)+[4,5])]

[list(j) for i in itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4],3) for j in itertools.permutations(list(i)+[4,5])]
```

Comment: is it for only k-permutations, as i mentioned?

Comment: I did not really focused on your proposed solution but it seems very useful, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think that the problem with your solution is that K value (K-permutations from N) will also be incremented every time when N will be incremented.

Comment: Because in my case I want that K stay fix for every new value added, so for each incremented value of N.

Comment: I have already found the modification in your solution that hold to the solution : I have to specify K in the permutation part: `itertools.permutations(list(i)+[4],3)]`. in this case 3.

Comment: For those who did not understand the interest of my task, is to calculate the k-permutation for a dynamic set which is incremented each time by new value. If we don't use the solution proposed by @Nahuel Fouilleul we recalculate every time permutations already calculated before. So with this solution we only calculate the k-permutation by permuting the new value with all existing ones and add the resulting permutations set to  the permutations set of all previous values. This will be very useful for a huge Sets and will save an important quantity of computation and time.

Answer (score 0):

try saving the existing permutations to a list, then do:

```
if newPermutation not in listOfExistingPermutations:
    listOfExistingPermutations.append(newPermutation)
```

or something along those lines

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the aim of this question is to avoid to repeat the computation of permutations that are already done, and proceed to the computation of the new permutations only.

Comment: My mistake, heres the only way I think its possible - there may be other methods: For each new set of starting numbers of length n, calculate the length L-1 combinations of that set, and then the individual permutations of each subset Except the combination that was used in the previous step: so if step1 is calculate permutations of [1, 2, 3], step 2 makes it [1, 2, 3, 4], then step3 is to find [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], and then each permutation from those 3 combinations